# Motion blur with photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I recently came across this problem: I must obtain a realistic motion blur effect, using photoshop CS6, starting from a still image of a car positioned on a bend.

I googled it and dicoverd a whole world of alternatives. As I understood the best option would be buying VIRTUAL RIG software or BLEEX (or even to upgrade photoshop as the CC version has something called Filter > Blur Gallery > Field Blur that maybe could help).

This guy uses BLENDER (http://fabricated.io/blog/motion-blur-revisited) but I did not find anybody that could explain me how.

Does anybody know how to achieve it with my photoshop version?

The desired final effect would be something like this: https://www.instagram.com/p/BWlqkAYAs2O/

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It’s best to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck, rather than requesting a tutorial. If you don’t know where to start then I would suggest a zoom blur of just the foreground, using layer masks to isolate the car and other areas that don’t need the motion blur.

Comment: It's all in the first link you provided; but you need to learn blender in order to be able to follow it. Or update Photoshop as you state yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sid,

As suggested by Westside, giving us some sense of what you've tried would help; also as Westside suggested a zoom blur would work.

I might myself choose to use motion blur, used on several different layers feathered and masked, each with a different motion blur angle, to get your multiple directions of motion feeling; I've done this to achieve a nonlinear feel to motion blur before. you could combine that with Westside's Zoom blur idea and end up with a strong visual with some care.

In Adobe CC, there's a specific blur tool for this in the Blur Gallery called *path blur* which would be *exactly* what you need for your task: if you've been considering the upgrade, maybe now is the time if the project for which you're doing this work has enough fee to absorb that cost, the savings in time will be well worth it.

The technique you referenced in Blender was actually pretty simple, *but* it does require a basic knowledge of how to use Blender, a decent asset for your hero item, decent shaders, and a good working knowledge of rendering in Blender with Cycles.

It boils down to taking a backing image (the one to be blurred) and applying it as a texture to a backing plane or mesh, then animating the hero car mesh against that backing mesh as it would actually move in the real world. You create a camera item, and parent it to the car mesh (this means that the camera will move with the car maintaining its spatial relationship and orientation) so that the camera is focussed on the car, and when you then render any one frame, that rendered output with motion blur will give a very close facsimile to photoreal motion blur - but again, that technique is completely dependent on you having a good-quality hero mesh in the first place, as I am assuming you don't have an extensive 3D modeling background enough to be modeling this car yourself, or I think you would have mentioned that in your post.

Hope some of this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop can be used. The original image:

[image]

The shot was taken through a bus window when the bus passed the place slowly.

Fake speeding:

[image]

The receipe:

1. The truck was copied and pasted into another layer and deleted from the background. The hole in the background was filled with surrounding elements. For it PS has content aware fill, which is selectable option when something is deleted in the background layer.

Cutting needed ordinary clipping path. Objects this complex cannot be selected properly with the magic wand or by using other easy methods.

Clipping paths are painful for beginners and making them takes time. The easy way is to use a separate vehicle image with no background and a clean background image which needs only the motion blur and possible vehicle shadow.

2. Truck's right side tyres were darkened to hide they are not spinning. left side tyres got radial spin blur.

Thet was complex because we had only parts if them visible and they are elliptical due the viewing direction. Several steps was needed:

- Copy those vehicle parts which partially cover the tyres into a separate layer
- paint or clone manually the tyres to complete. Good color is enough because spin blur hides all details

Both front and rear tyres are actually two elliptical shapes due their thickness. They must be spinned separately. The vertical surfaces are in layers "front spin foreground" and "rear spin foreground":

[image]

Elliptical tyre layers must be distorted back to circular before applying the radial spin blur. After blurring the tyres were stretched back to elliptical. Altough the tyre layers have nothing else, the tyre areas must be selected before applying the blur. Otherwise PS cannot place the spin center right.

All parts of the truck were duplicated and merged to a single layer. The part layers were hidedjust in case for error. Those parts of the spinning tyres which should be behind the concrete, were deleted.

The background got motion blur, special attention to the direction. Concrete wall was a good guide.

A joke: Cartoon style skew was given to the truck to make it a little agressive.

If you need a blur, where distant areas stay sharp, you can use radial zoom blur.  See an example:

[image]

There's a blurred layer and non blurred layer stacked. With radial gradient layer mask the blurred layer has got a hole which keep sharp the perspective vanishing point and a gradually fading area around it.

Canvas size is enlargened to shift the perspective vanishing point to the middle.

In Photohop CC the same is achieved more accurately and in a single layer with "path blur"